# Why does FixAntenna not add Tag 60 to New Order Single?

Tags: c#, fix-protocol

Why does FixAntenna not add Tag-60 (TransactionTime) automatically when I send a NewOrder Single (D) fix message?

I can't think that this tag needs to be added "manually".   ?

I am using Epam.FixAntenna.NetCore nuget package version 1.1.0

```
    FixMessage messageContent = new FixMessage();

    messageContent.AddTag(1, "LCE2");
    messageContent.AddTag(11, timestamp);
    messageContent.AddTag(15, "USD");
    messageContent.AddTag(21, 1);
    messageContent.AddTag(22, 8);
    messageContent.AddTag(38, msg.Qty);
    messageContent.AddTag(40, 2);
    messageContent.AddTag(44, msg.Price.ToString());
    messageContent.AddTag(48, msg.Symbol);
    messageContent.AddTag(54, msg.Side);
    messageContent.AddTag(55, msg.Symbol);
    messageContent.AddTag(59, msg.TimeInForce);
    messageContent.AddTag(128, "SAS");
        

    _orderSession.SendMessage("D", messageContent);
```

Comment: Bernard Sumner may help! :)

Comment: I don't have experience with FixAntenna, but why do you think that TransactTime should be added automatically? Are you maybe confusing it with SendingTime (which should be set by the engine when the message is actually sent).

Comment: Sending TIme is in the message - I can send TransactionTime manually  I just need to then remove the "-" between the integers of 2023-10-08.  If it could be done with the engine I would like that. It also makes sense to me that the engine can just do it - since TransactionTime is used to see whether there has been a lag in receiving the order due to a problem - why would that differ from SendingTime?

Comment: TransactTime is "Timestamp when the business transaction represented by the message occurred." This could be seconds, minutes or hours from when the message was sent, e.g. in the case when the FIX session was not connected. At least for NewOrderSingle it is *probably* nearly the same.